# Toggle between HTML code and preview using textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to Toggle between HTML code and Preview html using textarea

When HTML is clicked it would show the code hiding the textarea
and when again HTML is clicked it would show back again

I want to have design Something like this

[image]

I have tried with

```html
<style>
.container {
    width:500px;
    position: fixed;
}

.right-element {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="right-element">
        Preview
    </div>
  <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:75%;resize: none; " ><h3>At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. They offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.</h3></textarea>    
</div>
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I am bad english please edit my question if possible

Comment: I could but I am still not entirely sure what you're asking about - is your question about adding a header to a textarea? Or displaying the HTML directly inside the textarea and converting it back and forth?

Comment: There are many plugins available for that, this concept is called WYSIWYG(what you see is what you get).
either search on google or refer this plugin https://www.tiny.cloud/.

May the JS be with you!
Happy Coding!

Comment: Question is about adding a header to a textarea as well as displaying the HTML directly inside the textarea and converting it back and forth? Its something like bacic wysiwyg editor

Comment: @SwanandTaware Taware I dont want to use any plugins for just toggling between HTML preview

Answer (score 1):

You could have another `div` specifically for showing the preview. Then, when the user toggles the HTML view, insert the textarea's value into the `innerHTML` of the `div` and show it.

This could expose your application to XSS attacks though, so be careful when using it.

```js
$('.right-element').click(function() {
  $(this).toggle()
  $(this).siblings().toggle()
  togglePreview()
})

let showPreview = false
const w3Preview = $('#w3review-preview')

function togglePreview() {
  if (!showPreview) {
    w3Preview.html(w3review.value)
    w3Preview.show()
    $(w3review).hide()
  } else {
    w3Preview.hide()
    $(w3review).show()
  }
  showPreview = !showPreview
}
```

```css
#html,#w3review-preview{display:none}.container{position:fixed;width:500px}.right-element{background:red;display:inline-block;position:absolute;right:0;z-index:1}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="right-element" id="preview">
      Preview
    </div>
    <div class="right-element" id="html">
      HTML
    </div>
  </div>
  <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:75%;resize: none; "><h3>At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. They offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.</h3></textarea>
  <div id="w3review-preview" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:75%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolutely great Thank you so much, lastly can the preview button stay fixed outside textarea which will look like toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

Textarea can't display html, you can use div with attribute contenteditable instead like this:

```js
var w3reviewItem = $('#w3review');
var previewItem = $('#preview');

$(previewItem).on('click', (e) => {
  var type = $(w3reviewItem).attr('data-type');
  var textStr;
  switch(type) {
    case 'html': {
      textStr = $(w3reviewItem).html();
      $(w3reviewItem).attr('data-type', 'text');
      $(w3reviewItem).text(textStr);
      break;
    }
    case 'text': {
      textStr = $(w3reviewItem).text();
      $(w3reviewItem).attr('data-type', 'html');
      $(w3reviewItem).html(textStr);
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
<style>
.container {
    width:500px;
    position: relative;
}

.right-element {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    cursor: poniter;
    z-index: 999;
}

#w3review {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 70px; 
    border: 1px solid green;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="right-element" id="preview"> Preview </div>
  <div contenteditable="true" id="w3review" name="w3review" data-type="html">
    <h3>
      At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. They offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

This solution has a button that toggles between "Preview" and "Edit" using jQuery click. On click it grabs the textarea value, and sets a div with the value as HTML.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#previewButtonContainer button').click(function() {
    if($(this).data('preview')) {
      $(this).text('Preview').data('preview', '');
      $('#htmlEdit').show();
      $('#htmlPreview').hide();
    } else {
      $(this).text('Edit').data('preview', '1');
      let html = $('#htmlEdit').val();
      $('#htmlPreview').html(html);
      $('#htmlEdit').hide();
      $('#htmlPreview').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 502px;
}
#htmlEdit {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  resize: none;
  padding: 3px 6px;
}
#htmlPreview {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  display: none;
}
#previewButtonContainer {
  width: 60px;
  float: right;
}
#previewButtonContainer button {
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="previewButtonContainer"><button>Preview</button></div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  <div id="htmlPreview"></div>
  <textarea id="htmlEdit" name="htmlEdit" style=" " ><h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</h3> <p>consectetur adipiscing <b>elit</b>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut <b>labore</b> et <b>dolore</b> magna aliqua.</p></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I think iframe for preview is needed since the styles interfere with parent styles

Comment: I don't understand, what parent style?

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```js
function showHTML() {

  var innerText = document.getElementById("w3review").value;
  document.getElementById("w3review").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("htmlContainer").style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById("htmlContainer").innerHTML = innerText;

}

function showText() {

  document.getElementById("w3review").style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById("htmlContainer").style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  position: fixed;
}

.right-element {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#htmlContainer {
  display: "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="right-element" onClick="showText()">
    Preview
  </div>
  <div class="right-element" onClick="showHTML()">
    HTML
  </div>
  <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:75%;resize: none; "><h3>At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. They offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.</h3></textarea>
  <div id="htmlContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It should toggle and not using separate buttons

Comment: Also, inline attributes like `onClick` are a bad idea

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).